# validity of the lambda function return value

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, arduino, esp8266

I'm back to programming in C ++ after many years and I have some doubts.

I created this function:

```
typedef  std::function<const char *(void)> GetMessageLog;

void addLog(byte logLevel, GetMessageLog get)
{
  if (loglevelActiveFor(LOG_TO_SERIAL, logLevel)) {
    Serial.print(millis());
    Serial.print(F(" : "));
    Serial.println(get());
  }
  if (loglevelActiveFor(LOG_TO_SYSLOG, logLevel)) {
    syslog(logLevel, get());
  }
  if (loglevelActiveFor(LOG_TO_WEBLOG, logLevel)) {
    Logging.add(logLevel, get());
  }    
}
```

I would like to use it as follows:

```
addLog(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, [&]()
{
  String log = F("HX711: GPIO: SCL=");
  log += pinSCL;
  log += F(" DOUT=");
  log += pinDOUT;
  return log.c_str();
});
```

The validity of log.c_str () is guaranteed until addLog ends or if something interrupts the normal program flow (any event handler), the string object is destroyed?

Answer (score 4):

That actually depends on what `String` is, but most likely, the return value of `log.c_str()` is valid only as long as `log` itself is (that would certainly be the case with `std::string`). Which means that in your case, it's not usable at all: when the lambda returns, `log` is destroyed, so the pointer returned from the lambda is dangling already.

Fortunately, the solution is simple. Change the lambda's return type to `String` and have it return `log` itself instead. If you need a `const char*` eventually, you can call `c_str()` on the return value, where you will have much better control over the lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Is that Arduino API? That way you cause UB, String demolishes its resources on exit from closure.

Technically if you redesign type

```
typedef  std::function<String(void)> GetMessageLog;
```

then you can write

```
addLog(LOG_LEVEL_INFO, [&]() -> String
{
  String log = F("HX711: GPIO: SCL=");
  log += pinSCL;
  log += F(" DOUT=");
  log += pinDOUT;
  return log;
});
```

If compiler doesn't support named return value optimization, convert that in a one-liner to reduce amount of copy operations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The purpose of addLog so defined is that the call to the lambda method only if the condition of logLdvel is satisfied.If you add an overload, do not satisfy the purpose.

Comment: @Wee I see then only change signature of GetMessageLog. do not try pass internal pointer from string

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a local to the lambda so (assuming it's more or less like `std::string`) you cannot use `c_str` as return value because when the caller will access it the local is already dead.

One more potential problem is that you're capturing by reference with `[&]` the variables `pinSCL` and `pinDOUT`. If the lambda is stored away and its lifetime ends after the lifetime of those two variables then calling it is also undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
pinSCL and pinDOUT are local to the function that calls addLog.
C ++ does not guarantee validity until the caller function of addLog ends?

Comment: @Wee no, because lambda is separate scope. it's a closure by all means, essentially you created an object with `operator()`  and that contains member  variables - references to those captured ones, the body of lambda expression is that operator. Also one have to be wary if addLog actually calls lambda asynchronously, those references will die when local function would exit and lambda will be invalid

Comment: @6502 The purpose of addLog so defined is that the call to the lambda method only if the condition of logLevel is satisfied. addLog is called in many methods with heterogeneous information. How would you suggest me to implement it?

Comment: @Wee effectiveness issue: a) lambda object construction takes time. b) way how your `addLog` written it may call get() three times - unless those levels are exclusive - if they are, there is `else` forgotten? Would it be prudent to check if _any_ of required logging levels is active and call get() once?

Comment: @Wee: unfortunately C++ has no garbage collector and that is required for a full implementation of lambdas capturing by reference and outliving the scope that creates them (this is called the "upward funarg problem" in literature). What you can do is *copy* the values inside the lambda function instead of using references but that's not always practical (you can try to use also more complex solutions based on `shared_ptr` - but once again C++ has no garbage collector so you can end up leaking reference loops).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome back to C++! You'll find that it has changed quite a bit in this century, and for the better.

The object "String log" lives only during the call of addLog. You cannot return log.c_str() because this will return a dangling pointer to an object which will no longer exist after the return. The solution is simple - just return "log" itself. Have this function (and GetMessageLog) return not an old-style C "char *", but a modern C++ "std::string".

In old C++, returning an std::string from a function was often frowned upon, because it always involved *copying* of that string, sometimes multiple times. This is no longer true, with the advent of move constructors (which are probably the most important new feature in C++11). The function builds a string, and when returning it, the string is not copied but rather "moved" - which involves copying just the pointer which it holds to its data array, but not copying the array itself.

In modern C++, you will very rarely use old-style bare pointers like you used char* in this example. You will typically use objects like std::string instead of char*, containers like std::vector instead of int*, smart pointers like std::unique_ptr instead of T*. All these objects are safer than the bare pointers because they give you less chance to mess up the lifetime of the object, and are exception-safe (i.e., if an exception occurs in the middle of the code, you won't forget to free memory you allocated).

Comment: no, `std::string` isn't supported by ALL platforms (ISO actually doesn't require to implement _all_ classes). String is one of embedded platforms thing. And if that's that platform, then `unique_ptr` isn't present there at all.

Comment: std::string is definitely part of the C++11 standard. So is std::unique_ptr. If you're not using standard C++ with the full set of libraries but rather using some sort of trimmed-down version with different classes, then maybe you don't have those, but most likely you have non-standard variants of them. Like that "String", which presumably is similar to std::string, and like it has a move constructor, and everything I said above applies to it as well.

Comment: those are vendor standard for that platform and it's behavior in that matter is same though implementation is different (and not quite possible to be portable on PC platforms). Not having move constructors.. unless something was changed in new version, move is not so effective on Arduino. Closest thing I can think of is old-old Delphi set of classes, they are same by interface (to the constructor that does formatting)